# Flutter Bloc State won't be yielded after change from the Page pushed on top

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

The ***AddWorkoutEvent*** is dispatched correctly from the ***PageCreateWorkout*** with a ***DbMWorkout***.

This will be inserted in the correct table of the DB.
The ***PageCreateWorkout*** will be notified with the ***WorkoutAddedState*** to go to PageWorkoutDetail with the given ***workoutId***. The routes are stacked on the ***PageSelectWorkout***, in which the ***WorkoutBloc*** is mainly used, to show all workouts. In there the *PageSelectWorkout* shall be refreshed with the new ***WorkoutLoadedState*** with the newly given ***workoutList***. (The WorkoutList contains the added Workout, which I checked in the logger; but the State won't be yielded. Note that I am extending equatable to WorkoutStates.)

```
else if (event is AddWorkoutEvent) {
      logger.i("AddWorkoutEvent | workout: ${event.workout}");
      yield WorkoutLoadingState();
      try {
        DbMWorkout workout = await RepositoryWorkout.repo.add(event.workout);
        yield WorkoutAddedState(id: workout.id);
        List<DbMWorkout> workoutList = await RepositoryWorkout.repo.getAll();
        
        logger.i("AddWorkoutEvent | workoutListLength: ${workoutList.length}");

        yield WorkoutLoadedState(workoutList: workoutList); // <-- this state
      } catch (e) {
        yield WorkoutErrorState(message: e.toString());
      }
    }
```

The PageSelectWorkout is the initialPage of a Navigator in an indexedStack:

```
IndexedStack(
                sizing: StackFit.expand,
                index: _currentIndex,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Navigator(
                      key: _pageOverview,
                      initialRoute: PageOverview.routeName,
                      onGenerateRoute: (route) =>
                          RouteGenerator.generateRoute(route)),
                  Navigator(
                      key: _pageSelectWorkoutNew,
                      initialRoute: PageSelectWorkout.routeName,
                      onGenerateRoute: (route) =>
                          RouteGenerator.generateRoute(route)),
                  Navigator(
                      key: _pageLog,
                      initialRoute: PageLog.routeName,
                      onGenerateRoute: (route) =>
                          RouteGenerator.generateRoute(route)),
                  Navigator(
                      key: _pageSettings,
                      initialRoute: PageSettings.routeName,
                      onGenerateRoute: (route) =>
                          RouteGenerator.generateRoute(route))
                ]),
```

The named Route to the SelectWorkout is wrapped with the correct Bloc in a BlocProvider:

```
case PageSelectWorkout.routeName:
    return CupertinoPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (context) {
          return BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => WorkoutBloc(),
              child: PageSelectWorkout());
        });
```

Note: In other Events like ***DeleteWorkoutEvent*** , which is happening without navigating to another Page, the updated State gets yielded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after checking out some GitHub Issues and it's rather simple:
Since I want to access the same Bloc on 2 different Pages I ***can not*** just wrap a new Instance of the Bloc to each of the Page.

Instead I should wrap the BlocProvider with the WorkoutBloc higher in the WidgetTree Hierarchy for example in the **main.dart**

Before:

```
case PageSelectWorkout.routeName:
    return CupertinoPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => WorkoutBloc(), // <-- Instance of WorkoutBloc
            child: PageSelectWorkout()));

  case PageCreateWorkout.routeName:
    return CupertinoPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => WorkoutBloc(), // <-- Instance of WorkoutBloc
              child: PageCreateWorkout(
                workoutIndex: arguments["workoutIndex"],
                workoutPosition: arguments["workoutPosition"],
              ),
            ));
```

After:

```
case PageSelectWorkout.routeName:
    return CupertinoPageRoute(
        settings: settings, builder: (context) => PageSelectWorkout());

  case PageCreateWorkout.routeName:
    return CupertinoPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (context) => PageCreateWorkout(
        workoutIndex: arguments["workoutIndex"],
        workoutPosition: arguments["workoutPosition"],
      ),
    );
```

and higher in the Inheritance/WidgetTree Hierarchy e.g. ***main.dart*** :

```
return MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  title: Strings.appTitle,
                  theme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
                  home: MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
                    BlocProvider<WorkoutBloc>(
                      create: (context) => WorkoutBloc(), // <-- put the Instance higher
                    ),
                    BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
                      create: (context) => NavigationBloc(),
                    ),
                  ], child: BottomNavigationController()));
```